# MATLAB: Math Models for Computer Science

Tags: matlab

I have question that needs to be done in MATLAB but before that I need to find the solution of the question mathematically, The question is:

Five points A,B,C,D1,D2 in R^3 are given.

(a) Determine whether three points A,B,C are collinear (lie in same line)

(b) If A,B,C are not collinear, find the plane that contains that three points

(c) Determine whether D1 and D2 are in the A,B,C plane

(d) If D1 AND D2 are not in A,B,C plane, find the point of intersection of A,B,C-plane and D1D2-line

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i have tried to find 4 lines that are not collinear

Comment: @user3500261: 4 lines that are collinear?

Comment: sorry, I found 3 noncollinear points where these 3 points determines a plane. So this is how I answered:

Comment: 1) N0    2) I drawn the graph, a triange, and said: A plane contains A,B,C where A,B,C are noncollinear

Comment: 3) no D1 and D2 are not in the ABC-plane (4) I gave an exaple: let the equation of the plane be 2x+y-3z+5=0 and the line that intersecs be (x+2)/3=(y-1)/2=(z+6)/1 THEN I found the point where d1 and d2 intersects with plane ABC WHICH is M(-14,-7,-10)

Answer (score 1):

If you spend a few minutes to understand the following code snippet,  you will understand the "mathematical" solution as well.

```
// The five points, assumed all distinct.
A = [1 0 0]';
B = [0 1 0]';
C = [0 0  1]';

D1 = [0 0 0]';
D2 = [0.5 0.5 0.5]';

// Not necessary to form the matrix M. Used for convenient plotting.
M = [A B C];

hold on
grid on

// Plot all the points and the line.
for i = 1:3
    plot3(M(1,i), M(2,i), M(3,i), '.', 'MarkerSize', 24)
end
plot3(D1(1), D1(2), D1(3), 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 24)
plot3(D2(1), D2(2), D2(3), 'r.', 'MarkerSize', 24)
plot3([D1(1) D2(1)], [D1(2) D2(2)], [D1(3) D2(3)], 'k', 'LineWidth', 2)
view(120, 20)

// Cross product of B-A and C-A
cp = cross(B-A, C-A);

// Are A, B, and C collinear?
if norm(cp) == 0
    disp('The points are collinear')
else
    disp('The points are not collinear')
    // In this case, find the plane defined by the three points.
    syms x  y z
    plane_eq = [x y z]*cp;
    offset = subs(plane_eq, {x, y, z}, {A(1), A(2), A(3)});
    disp(['The equation of the plane is ' char(plane_eq) ' = ' num2str(offset)])
    u = get(gca, 'XLim');
    v = get(gca, 'YLim');
    h = ezmesh(char(solve(plane_eq - offset, z)), [u v]);
    set(h, 'EdgeColor', [0 0 0], 'FaceColor', 'none')
    if norm((D1-A)'*cp) ~= 0
        disp('D1 does not lie in the plane.')
    end

    if norm((D2-A)'*cp) ~= 0
        disp('D2 does not lie in the plane.')
    end

    M = [D1-D2 B-A C-A];
    b = D1 - A;
    t = inv(M)*b;
    ip = D1 + t(1)*(D2 - D1);
    disp(['The intersection point is [' num2str(ip') '].'])
    plot3(ip(1), ip(2), ip(3), 'g.', 'MarkerSize', 24)

end
```

And some visualisation

[image]